# My character controller is automatically applying gravity in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working in Unity using C# and I have encountered a problem with my code. The Character Controller that I attached to my player is automatically dragging the player down. I am aware that the CC is causing this behaviour as without the CC enabled or present, my player remains fixed in space. Unfortunately, having read the Unity documentation on the CC, I'm unable to find anywhere that describes this functionality or how to turn it off.

I would prefer to not have to remove the CC altogether, as it is useful for many first person mechanics, but I'm pretty stumped and can't work out where I am going wrong. I need the gravity to be under my control due to problems that it's causing with my jump mechanics. Thank you in advance for any ideas, please see the video bellow for a demonstration of the problem.

```
public CharacterController controller;
public float walkSpeed = 3f;
public float runSpeed = 6f;
public float gravity = -9.81f;
public float jumpHeight = 4f;

void Start()
{
}

void Update()
{

    if ((Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")))
    {
        Vector3 antigravity = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity), 0);
        controller.Move(antigravity);
    }

    if ((Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0) || (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0))
    {
        float xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float zInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float running = Input.GetAxis("Fire3");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * xInput + transform.forward * zInput;

        if (running > 0)
        {
            controller.Move((move * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
        else
        {
            controller.Move(move * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I have not interacted with the CC in any other way except through the code above.

https://youtu.be/8gprUJLzvHk

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered the same issue, "normally" the character controller does not apply gravity.... all the information and tutorials will tell you to roll your own which I have.

But if you apply root motion and bake the Y into the animation it does apply Physics.Gravity... I can only guess that it is applying SimpleMove() instead of Move() on the CharacterController internally if root motion is applied but Y is baked.

Only solutions I can see are:

1. Set gravity to Zero in the project settings (not very flexible).
2. Don't bake the Y into your animations with root motion.

Comment: I genuinely just figured I was going mad... :') I'm glad this wasn't all in my imagination.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I took a different approach and changed my code, the following code is now functional although I have no idea what was causing the original issue still.

```
public CharacterController controller;
private float speed; 
public float walkSpeed = 5f;
public float runSpeed = 10f;
public float turnSpeed = 90f; 
public float jumpSpeed = 8f;
public float gravity = 9.8f;
private float vSpeed = 0f; 

void  Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire3"))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        Vector3 vel = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * runSpeed;
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            vSpeed = 0;
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            { 
                vSpeed = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }
        vSpeed -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        vel.y = vSpeed; 
        controller.Move(vel * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        speed = walkSpeed;
        transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        Vector3 vel = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * walkSpeed;
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            vSpeed = 0;
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                vSpeed = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }
        vSpeed -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        vel.y = vSpeed;
        controller.Move(vel * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

This happens because the character controller has a gravity so when you enable it, it uses gravity to the player and drag your player down. To fix this, you will need to write in the script that the player's position is upwards.

```
public float walkSpeed = 3f;
public float runSpeed = 6f;
public float gravity = -9.81f;
public float jumpHeight = 4f;

if ((Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")))
{
    Vector3 antigravity = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity), 0);
    controller.Move(antigravity);
}

if ((Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0) || (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0))
{
    float xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float zInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float running = Input.GetAxis("Fire3");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * xInput + transform.forward * zInput;

    if (running > 0)
    {
        controller.Move((move * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
    else
    {
        controller.Move(move * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, 15, 0); //Set your player position
    }
    
} // If this doesn't help, tell me what's the problem.
```

Comment: This has not worked unfortunately, also, I should have clarified that the code I posted previously is already within the Update() method. transform.position has no effect on my player controller, neither does disabling gravity in the CC's attached rigid body.